# "Unable to load manifest file"

Tags: technical-issues, portal-2

When I start Portal 2, I get the following error message:
[image: Error message]

Afterwards, the game just crashes, leaving me unable to play the game.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You never ask your question, and nobody will be able to help you if you don't be very specific with your question.

Comment: Have you tried verifying your local files in Steam?

Comment: Everything I find on the internet about this points to file paths being incorrect.  https://steamcommunity.com/app/17520/discussions/2/648814845566466176/ for example - not the same game, but it is a Source Engine game.

Comment: How was it installed?

Comment: Ive tried Verifying And Reinstalling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the contents of this file on my linux machine (which shouldn't matter). I've removed the comments included with it for brevity.

```
surfaceproperties_manifest
{
    "file"      "scripts/surfaceproperties.txt"
    "file"      "scripts/surfaceproperties_portal.txt"
    "file"      "scripts/surfaceproperties_portal2.txt"
}
```

The file is located in my

```
.../steam/steamapps/common/Portal 2/portal2/scripts/
```

directory. I'll assume from your question that this file isn't already present there.

Comment: I believe in my searches for an answer to this question I saw someone try to just give the code of the script as you did, and it did not appear to resolve the issue.